# Bash sftp expect Script Does Not Continue After Retrieving Multiple Files

Tags: sftp, expect

I need to script out a way to FTP files from a remote server. I cannot use keys, so the login needs to be "interactive". I felt that expect was the way to go.

I have the following expect code in a bash script:

```
expect <<EOD
    spawn sftp $sftp_user@$sftp_svr
    expect "password:"
    send "$sftp_pw\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "mget $getfile_path$getfile_name $savefile_path\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "bye\r"
EOD
```

The snippet works fine when it only retrieves one file. However, if I need to retrieve more than one file the final "expect sftp>" is never acted on.
Working:

```
[ed@svr1 ~]$ ./sftp_expect.sh
spawn sftp user@svr2
user@svr2's password:
Connected to svr2.
sftp> mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt /home/ed/report_received/
Fetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt
/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                   100%   56    26.9KB/s   00:00
sftp>
[ed@svr1 ~]$
```

Not Working:

```
[ed@svr1 ~]$ ./sftp_expect.sh
spawn sftp user@svr2
user@svr2's password:
Connected to svr2.
sftp> mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck*.txt /home/ed/report_received/
Fetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt
/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                   100%   56    26.5KB/s   00:00
Fetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck2.txt
/data/hf_user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                   100%   56    19.3KB/s   00:00
Fetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck_svr2.txt
/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                            100%   56    31.9KB/s   00:00
sftp>
^C
[ed@svr1 ~]$
```

The script gets the files, expect gets "what it's expecting" but it does not continue on:

```
expect: does "mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck*.txt /home/ed/report_received/\r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    24.5KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    38.3KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck_svr2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "sftp> "? no
/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                              100%   56    25.7KB/s   00:00

expect: does "mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck*.txt /home/ed/report_received/\r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    24.5KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    38.3KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck_svr2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                              100%   56    25.7KB/s   00:00    \r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "sftp> "? no
sftp>
expect: does "mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck*.txt /home/ed/report_received/\r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    24.5KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    38.3KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck_svr2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                              100%   56    25.7KB/s   00:00    \r\nsftp> " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "sftp> "? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "sftp> "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "mget /data/user/upload/lastcheck*.txt /home/ed/report_received/\r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck1.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck1.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    24.5KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                       0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck2.txt                                                                                                                                                                     100%   56    38.3KB/s   00:00    \r\nFetching /data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt to /home/ed/report_received/lastcheck_svr2.txt\r\n\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                                0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA\r/data/user/upload/lastcheck_svr2.txt                                                                                                                                                              100%   56    25.7KB/s   00:00    \r\nsftp> "
send: sending "bye\r" to { exp6 }

^C
[ed@svr2 ~]$
```

If anyone has an idea what is holding up the expect piece I would very much appreciate it.

Ed.

Answer (score -1):

```
expect <<EOD
    set timeout -1
    spawn sftp $sftp_user@$sftp_svr
    expect "password:"
    send "$sftp_pw\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "mget $getfile_path$getfile_name $savefile_path\r"
    expect "sftp> "
    send "bye\r"
EOD
```